# ODBC linked database with / in field name

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to link an ODBC database - which I have no control on - in MS Access 2007 using a `Machine Data Source` - I don't know if that's relevant, from what I got this means that the access is set only on this computer -.

When I follow the wizard I can select the table but when the time comes to link it I get the error message:

`The database engine can't find 'WTD.DATAPOINT_5/1000'. Make sure it is a valid parameter or alias name, that it doesn't include characters or punctuation, and that the name isn't too long`

I think that the problem is that one of the field is named `WTD.DATAPOINT_5/1000` and that Access interprets `/`as a symbol of its own.

The thing is that I don't even need the data stored in this column. Right now I don't know which way to go.

1. Find a way to tell Access that the `/` is part of the field name. (Highly improbable)
2. Retrieve only some fields from the table using built-in Access functions.
3. Set the connection manually using vba and retrieving only some of the fiels. If this is the way to go I would like some pointers as I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution number 2: use a passthrough SQL query.

[Everything is explained in this tutorial.](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/passthrough/basics01.php)

Solution number 3: I tried to connect directly in VBA. The code bellow works like a charm for other tables but I still get an error for the table containing the problematic field.

```
Dim ConnectionStr As String
ConnectionStr = "ODBC;Driver={Oracle in OraHome92};Dbq=BLA1;Uid=BLA2;Pwd=BLA3;"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", ConnectionStr, acTable, "MyTable", "NewTable"
```